# Youtube api v3 browser based upload throwing 400 error

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on youtube browser based video upload. but its throwing an error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>invalid_value</code><location type='xpath'>media:group/media:category[@scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat']/text()</location></error></errors>' in /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/Zend/Gdata/App.php:714 Stack trace: #0 /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...', NULL) #1 /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/Zend/Gdata/App.php(905): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...') #2 /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php(704): Zend_Gdata_App->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry), 'http://gdata.yo...') #3 /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/video_upload. in /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 714`

Code:

```
<?php
// video_upload.php


require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

// Define the authentication that will be used
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'); 

// Authenticate
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = 
Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
          $username = "example@gmail.com",
          $password = "example",
          $service = 'youtube',
          $client = null,
          $source = 'HTML SOURCE CODE SNIPPET',
          $loginToken = null,
          $loginCaptcha = null,
          $authenticationURL);

$applicationId = 'YOUR APPLICATION ID';
$clientId = 'Upload videos to youtube using the youtube API';
$developerKey = 'A...........................0';
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);



// create a new VideoEntry object
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('video');
// The category must be a valid YouTube category!
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('news');

// Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
// and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('news');

$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl."?nexturl=//example.com/up");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// same as <input type="file" name="file">
$post = array("file"=>"@".$VideoFile['tmp_name'], "token"=>$tokenValue);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo $info;
?>
```

Form:

```
    <form action="video_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>
```

I want to upload video directly to my youtube account.so users can upload video to my youtube account..

So i m not adding anything to `$applicationId` and `$clientId`.

I think something need to be done with `$applicationId` and `$clientId`.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

As **Wanny Miarelli** suggested
i changed `news` to `News` and now no error is showing, but video also not uploaded.

tried  `print_r($info)` and got this

```
Array
(
   [url] => http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/AIwbFAS1SkX04C09Re5sWeYXb562vc7W5KHcRu0uZcJ7v-A4nX_21zVwIOxdeBtp_s4tj-UcnZxJaN-Zd7nKVUfWwtWxW2YEPg?nexturl=//example.com/up
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.024856
    [namelookup_time] => 0.018251
    [connect_time] => 0.024751
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: it seems that something is wrong with the category "news", try to see if there is something wrong. I'm trying to understand more, but the documentation is lacking in this.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses

Comment: You should be able to see the video being uploaded from your youtube account while it's being uploaded. Try using Charles or Fiddler to analyse your network connections and see if the video even starts downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, seems a category problem. Try to change " news " to " News "

Look there for a complete category List

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Region_specific_feeds

this is the direct download to the .cat File

http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat

this is what Goolge should send you after video upload ( success or fail )

> > After uploading the video file, the user is redirected to the nexturl specified in your form. If the upload was successful, YouTube
> >     appends id and status parameters to the URL as shown in the following
> >     example:
>
> http://www.example.com/youtube_uploads?status=200&id=JPF-DXF7hzc If
>   the upload was not successful, YouTube appends status and code
>   parameters to the URL to help you diagnose the cause of the failure.
>   The reference guide provides more information about these parameters.

Ok, i jsut set up a zend framework istance, and this code works for me

**THIS CODE IS EXPLANATORY PURPOSES ONLY- NOT SECURE AND NOT OPTIMAL **

The user wants to upload the video with a One Step Form, this is the solution

```
    <?php

            //single file script, need to know if we are in a POST or GET request, this needs to be changed, dividing the script into a separate file 

            if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){


              Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
              Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

              $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';

              $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
                            $username = '',
                            $password = '',
                            $service = 'youtube',
                            $client = null,
                            $source = 'TestApp', // a short string identifying your application
                            $loginToken = null,
                            $loginCaptcha = null,
                            $authenticationURL);


              $applicationId = 'TestAPP';
              $developerKey = "---";
              $clientId = "";

              // Note that this example creates an unversioned service object.
              // You do not need to specify a version number to upload content
              // since the upload behavior is the same for all API versions.
              $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);

              // create a new VideoEntry object
              $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

              $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($_POST['Title']);
              $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($_POST['Description']);
              // The category must be a valid YouTube category!
              $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('News');

              // Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
              // and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
              $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('News');

              $tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
              $tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
              $tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
              $postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];

              // place to redirect user after upload
              $nextUrl = 'http://localweb/';

              $target_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/accept.php';
            //This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
                $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('C:\video.flv');
                      /* curl will accept an array here too.
                       * Many examples I found showed a url-encoded string instead.
                       * Take note that the 'key' in the array will be the key that                    shows up in the
                       * $_FILES array of the accept script. and the at sign '@' is required before the
                       * file name.
                       */

                 // Post the video to Youtube Server
                $post = array('token' => $tokenValue,'file_contents'=>'@'. $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl . '?nexturl=' . $nextUrl);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                $result=curl_exec ($ch);
                curl_close ($ch);
                echo $result;


    }else{

      $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

      $form = '<form action="' . $self  . '"'.
            ' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'. 
            '<input name="file" id="file" type="file"/>'. 
            '<input name="token" id="token" type="hidden" value=""/>'.
            '<input name="Description" id="Description" />'.
            '<input name="Title" id="Title" />'.
            '<input value="Upload Video File" type="submit" />'. 
            '</form>';

            echo $form;
    }
```

Comment: no error now, but video not uploaded to youtube ,and got a response `Array` only

Comment: how big is this video? it must finish loading, and processing before it can be seen on youtube

Comment: m already using [https://github.com/malsup/form](https://github.com/malsup/form) for progress bar

Comment: i added status code it shows `Fatal error: Call to a member function getVideoState() on a non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/yyy.com/up/video_upload.php on line 65` i added below php code

Comment: look at the update, I'm trying to figure out =) the documentation is fairly generic

Comment: let me set up Zend, i'll check and report.

Comment: if it is not clear, let me know, i'll reorganize the answer, I tend to be messy!

Comment: oops sorry i didn't saw your edit..let me try that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44427/discussion-between-gopal-and-wanny-miarelli)

Comment: HI...i had  tested it and its uploading videos but its not returning the video id :(

Comment: After uploading the video file, the user is redirected to the nexturl specified in your form. If the upload was successful, YouTube appends id and status parameters to the URL.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?hl=it&csw=1#Uploading_Videos

Comment: i had tried it but it says class not found..so i extracted the id from the curl response and thanks for your help :)